# How to set up ATG development environment for use with JBoss

Tags: atg

Can somebody please explain all the steps involved in setting up ATG development environment for use with JBoss AS.
My requirement is simple, I need to develop and deploy a simple J2EE applicaiton containing a few forms and backend logic to save the data entered in the forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is also in ATG documentation that comes with the product

Installation and Configuration guide:
http://www.atg.com/repositories/ContentCatalogRepository_en/manuals/ATG9.1/atginstall/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm

and Programming Guide, chapter 3.

At minimum you need:

- ATG installed (e.g. in c:\ATG\ATG9.1)
- JBoss installed (e.g. in c:\opt\jboss) - make sure you use supported version of JBOss for the ATG version you use - e.g. 4.2.0 for ATG 9.1, 4.0.5 for ATG2007.1
- installed JDK - again, version matters, Java 5 is what you want
- Eclipse + Eclipse plugin from www.atg.com/eclipse
- Ant installed
- database installed (for development, MySQL is good choice)

Set the environment variables to ATG_HOME, ATG_ROOT

Verify that the setup works with MotorpriseJSP - start Solid, deploy EAR file and try it out

Now you are ready to start development. At high level, you want:

- define database schemas and create ATG tables
- load initial data to database
- define new module under ATG_ROOT, with proper structure and MANIFEST (this is what Eclipse will help you with)
- code custom functionality (this may include extending user profile, product catalog or define custom repositories)
- define datasource file for your database and place it into JBOss/server/atg/deploy
- using startDynamoOnJBoss try out if your module loads
- using Ant task, build the EAR file for standalone deployment

I honestly do not see any way how to avoid following the docs. The real answer would be tens/hundreds of pages long.

You should dedicate enough time reading few thousands pages of ATG documentation and trying it out. There are two way how to speed things up: working along with somebody who did it before and knows ATG or attending the ATG training (Boston or SF). Ideally training first and having mentor / working on real project right after that.

Answer (score 1):

Get access to ATG documentation and join ATG community at https://community.atg.com/community/catalyst. They have docs to your questions.